# How to get user data from Google API with OAuth remotely from a server?

Tags: google-oauth

I've been reading lots of documentation about Google API access and OAuth flow using it but I don't seem to get it working in my mind, so I want to get some help first in order to have a clear idea about how it works then I can code it using the corresponding API.

What I want to achieve is feed a Java application running in a PC with specific Google user data, like localization through Google Latitude API. In order to get this, OAuth must be used, so I need getting the user consent, then access the user data from the application running in my computer, and I don't know how to manage this.

I've already registered my application with the Google APIs Console and enabled the Google Latitude module. I've also tried the Latitude console application [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Google_Latitude_API) and it works properly (a browser tab opened asking for a Google user; I entered it and I got the location data), but I'm having problems when trying to adapt the program flow to my needs.

In my application, the 'remote' user is supposed to send a request (a custom JSON message) to the server asking for service enable/disable, like allowing the server to track his/her position through Latitude. Then, AFAIK, the server should send to the user a URL so the user can give the consent, but I don't know how to get this URL and how the server realizes about this consent and gets the token (automatically? Google tracks this authorization process?). Once my server gets the specific user token, then I should be ready to get service data for that user using the received token.

As I said before, I've tried according to different references, but as the documentation seems to be really scattered and much of it is already deprecated, I've been unable to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your description, the installed app OAuth2 flow seems to be the right one for you.

At some point, presumably when a user is installing your desktop app, you should fire up a browser - either embedded one in your app or the default browser - and sent them to [this](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth) Google OAuth2 endpoint. In your request, fill out all the parameters as required by the [doc](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp): Latitude API scope, client_id, etc. Google, as an authorization server, will take care of user authentication, session selection, and user consent. If the user grants access to her data to your API, you will receive an authorization code either in the title of the browser window or at a localhost port.

Once you have the code, you can exchange it for an access token and a refresh token. The access token is what you need to call the API and access the user's data. It is short lived though - check the expired_in parameter in the response, I believe it is 3600 sec. - so you will need to periodically ping the token endpoint with your long lived refresh token and exchange it for an access token.

You can find a more thoroough description of this flow in the doc linked above.

Comment: Well, the problem here is that the application that needs the user consent to access the Latitude data is not a desktop application, but a web application. I mean, the user enables/disables the service access permission through a message sent to the server, which is in charge to manage the authorization flow. Thus, the server needs to build the request for Google's authorization server with the client id, redirect URI and all required data. Can I set a web application for my users to access it and then set a proper redirect URI so the token/consent is sent to the server?

Comment: I see. In that case I would suggest to look at the web server flow. You can initiate the OAuth2 flow from the client web app, but use a redirect URI that will send the authorization code to your server. Your server can exchange it for a refresh token, and you will be able to exchange the refresh token for an access one. There is one catch: you will need to request offline access, since the user won't be present at your server when you're exchanging the tokens or making the API calls. More information here: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Currently I'm struggling with redirect URI building (it seems that Google API does not accept an IP address to be used...) while following what you pointed out.